# What could be the correct way of printing the below log line of Mono<Void> and not donOnsucess : subscribe() in reactive

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am getting my log.info printed successfully
However I am suggested not subscribe() in doOnSuccess here.

If I don't do that no execution happen for MyBoMono.map, no log printed, it directly moves to next point.

Here is the sample code

```
public Mono<Void> test() {
    
    Mono<MyBo> MyBoMono = service.getFirstcall();

    return service.getAnothercall()
        .zipWith(MyBoMono)
        .flatMap(objects -> { //some code })
        .doOnSuccess(aVoid -> {
            MyBoMono.map(MyBo -> {
                log.info("=====> PRINTING THE LOGS ===== {}", MyBo);
                return Mono.empty();
            }).subscribe();
        })
        .doOnError(throwable -> { //some code });
```

}

Is there any correct way to print the log if I do not subscribe?

Comment: you can use `flatMap` instead of `doOnSuccess`

Comment: if i put flatmap then its lambda would be void again, means what would be the code for MyBoMono in that flatmap?

Comment: Not sure I exactly follow what your goal is. Maybe you can use `then` which is also executed after an empty Mono: `.then(MyBoMono.doOnNext(MyBo -> log.info("=====> PRINTING THE LOGS ===== {}", MyBo)).then())`

Comment: Why don't you log inside `flatMap`?

Answer (score 0):

If you do something like this the subscription in doOnSUccess won't print anything. In deed the zipWith operator will subscribe to MyBoMono and will emit a value and complete immediately. Therefore any further subscription will complete (empty value).

An alternative is to return the result of the mono in your flatMap method

```java
service.getAnothercall()
    .zipWith(MyBoMono)
    .flatMap(tuple -> {
      //do whatever you want
      .thenReturn(tuple.getT2())
    }).doOnSuccess(myBoValue -> log.info("=====> PRINTING THE LOGS ===== {}",myBoValue))
...
```

Be aware when using zip/zipWith operator that an error or empty completion of any source will cause the other source to be cancelled and the resulting Mono to immediately error or complete, respectively.

Comment: I uderstood your point JEY, with this it will cause error due to mono<void> return type : Required type & Provided..but yes taking that value in that way could be a way otherwise

Comment: currently i took that doOnSuccess in my flat map, where after return of api.doOnSuccess() { // using the tuple.getT2()}
Thanks